# Hook module placement

Tags: hooks

I have the following file named background_image_style.module

In my Drupal 8.3.3 site, paragraphs.module is at MySite/web/modules/contrib/paragraphs/paragraphs.module.

I installed the site and all contributed modules with Composer.

```
composer require drupal/paragraphs
vendor\bin\drupal module:install paragraphs
```

Where does my hook module go? (I just copied it in where the paragraphs.module is.) Are there any other overhead steps that needs to be done (e.g. editing other files)?

I tried several locations and cleared the cache each time.

```
    /**
     * Implements paragraphs().
     */ 
    function background_image_style_preprocess_paragraph__banner(&$variables) {
      $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
      if (!$paragraph->field_image->isEmpty()) {
        $image = $paragraph->field_image->entity->url();
        $variables['attributes']['style'][] = 'background-image: url("' .                 $image. '");';
        $variables['attributes']['style'][] = 'background-size: cover;';
        $variables['attributes']['style'][] = 'background-position: center         center;';
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Where to Put the Module Files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/extending-drupal-8/installing-modules#mod_location):

> **Manual import location**
>
> If you import a module 'manually', you should place your module in that same default recommended location, *HERE*:
>
> [d8-root]/modules/*HERE*
>
> [Themes: [d8-root]/themes/*HERE*]

It's a good idea to keep custom and contrib modules separate, hence Drupal Project putting contributed modules into their own folder; following on from that, there's a pretty common convention to place custom modules under [d8-root]/modules/custom/. But you don't have to, you can use whatever hierarchy you like under /modules, Drupal will pick up anything it finds recursively.

After it's in place, don't forget to *enable* the module, or it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This preprocess hook can go right in the `themename.theme` file. In the theme, the name of the hook needs to be `themename_preprocess_paragraph__banner` (where `themename` is the name of your active theme).

Otherwise it would have to go in a custom module, and the hook name would be the module name instead of the theme name.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the .yml file missing. A little different from d7 but more or less the same concept.